# Timer (using boost chrono steady_clock) expires after computer time is set forward on Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: linux, boost, 64-bit, c++-chrono

We are using boost:chrono for the Timer implementation. Below is our implementation:

```
boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock> untilTime(boost::chrono::steady_clock::now() + boost::chrono::milliseconds(dueTime));

boost::condition_variable  m_condition;
(void)m_condition.wait_until(guard, untilTime);
```

After computer time on Ubuntu Linux 64-bit (tested with 12.04 and 15.04) is set forward for the time bigger then timer interval, timer expires immediately.

We have reproduced the problem with different boost versions 1.51, 1.54,1.55,1.57,1.59

On Ubuntu Linux 32-bit (versions 12.04, 13.04) and Windows 7 (32-bit and 64-bit) problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock

is not a spec.

[N4527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) is a spec, albeit, not an official one.  It is the latest working draft of the C++ spec.  It says in 20.12.7.2/p1:

> Objects of class `steady_clock` represent clocks for which values of
>   `time_point` never decrease as physical time advances and for which
>   values of `time_point` advance at a steady rate relative to real time.
>   That is, the clock may not be adjusted.

I note your use:

```
(void)m_condition.wait_until(guard, untilTime);
```

ignores the return value of `wait_until`.  Note that this function may return *spuriously*.  That is, it may return even though not signaled, and even though the timeout has not expired.

You can discover if the timeout has expired with:

```
if (m_condition.wait_until(guard, untilTime) == std::cv_status::timeout)
    ...
```

It could be (and I'm guessing) that your OS considers an adjustment of the system time a sufficiently drastic event that it is prudent to spuriously signal all condition variables.